# What type of math problem is this and how do I solve it? The question is: What “Input Setting” will result in the maximum Efficiency for this vehicle?

Tags: functions

[image]

Image is above^

What type of math problem is this and how do I solve it? The question is: What “Input Setting” will result in the maximum Efficiency for this vehicle?

Comment: Look at the graph. What speed has the highest efficiency? Now look at the table. Which "input setting" produces this speed?

Comment: I’m still confused..

Comment: @Ocean What confuses you? (I mean this question very sincerely. We need to know what confuses you in order to help.)

Comment: Doesn’t speed 6 have the highest efficiency?

Comment: @Ocean Why do you think that? What do you think the efficiency is when the speed is 6 cm/sec? When the speed is 2 cm/sec, I think the efficiency is 60%.

Comment: @Ocean There is no formula for solving something like this. This is testing your ability to read a graph and then read a table.

Answer (score 0):

This question requires you to locate the maximum turning point (i.e. maximum efficiency you want to determine) on the given graph. By eyeballing, we see this maximum efficiency occurs when **speed = 2cm/sec**.

From your given Table A, Input Setting V is 8, to produce **speed = 2cm/sec**

Hence, an **Input Setting of 8** will result in max efficiency.

Comment: I’m still confused..